# Multidimensional mixed array vs static classes vs anything else?

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the right structure to store some global variables. I basically have 2 set of similar variables grouped under Option A/B. The choice between A and B set is done from the app.config. The data have the following structure:

```
[OptionA][VAR1] = "myValue1OptionA"
[OptionA][VAR2] = {'a','b','c'}
[OptionA][VAR3] = 3
[OptionB][VAR1] = "myValue1OptionB"
[OptionB][VAR2] = {'a','b','c','d','e'}
[OptionB][VAR3] = 120
```

I can use a dictionary with a tuple as index but it is a bit heavy in term of casting when using the variables:

```
private static GlobalVar<Tuple<string, string>, var> instances = 
            new Dictionary<Tuple<string, string>, var>(){
            {Tuple.Create("OptionA","VAR1"), "myValue1OptionA"},
            {Tuple.Create("OptionA","VAR2"), {'a','b','c'}},
            {Tuple.Create("OptionA","VAR3"), 3},
            {Tuple.Create("OptionB","VAR1"), "myValue1OptionB"},
            {Tuple.Create("OptionB","VAR2"), {'a','b','c','d','e'}},
            {Tuple.Create("OptionB","VAR3"), 120},
            };
```

I thought of 2 statics classes but retrieving the values and casting is also a bit cumbersome.

```
static class GlobalVarOptionA
{
    static string VAR1 = "myValue1OptionA";
    static char[] VAR2 = {'a','b','c'};
    static int VAR3 = 3;
}

static class GlobalVarOptionB
{
    static string VAR1 = "myValue1OptionB";
    static char[] VAR2 = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    static int VAR3 = 120;
}
```

Usage should be something like:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("GlobalVarOptionB");
var pinfo = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Any help/advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the choice between A and B comes form the app.config file, this means it is done once at startup of your program.

So you should create/initialize just **one** of these structures in memory after the app.config is read.

Because it is structured data (as opposed to a string/string list) I'd use a static class as you did with `static class GlobalVarOption`

Answer (score 1):

For me better approach will be one static class with properties where you can internally check which option to return

or use singleton pattern

```
class GlobalVariables
{

   public static GlobalVariables Instance = new GlobalVariables();

   public readonly string VAR1;
   public readonly char[] VAR2;
   public readonly int VAR3;

   private GlobalVariables()
   {
      // Set values based on the App.config options
   }
}
```

Using

```
GlobalVariables.Instance.VAR1
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did exactly this :-)